# BubbleWrap RSSParser to TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, rubymotion

I am using RubyMotion, BubbleWrap::RSSParser, and ProMotion. My goal is to read an RSS feed with BubbleWrap::RSSParser to popular a TableView.

I have the following setup:

```
def on_init
  @data = []
end

def table_data
  [{
    title: "",
    cells: @data
  }]
end

def on_load
  @data = []
  feed = BW::RSSParser.new("URL")
  feed.parse do |item|
    @data << item.to_hash
  end
  @data
end
```

For some reason, the `@data` array is `nil`, but when I do `p item.to_hash` the hash prints out correctly to the console.

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be because the RSSParser is an asynchronous request. You probably return `@data` empty, before the request is completed.

EDIT: From BubbleWrap [docs](http://bubblewrap.io/), you can set a delegate for the parser. Something like

```
feed_parser = BW::RSSParser.new("http://feeds.feedburner.com/sdrbpodcast")
feed_parser.delegate = self 
feed_parser.parse do |item|
  @data << item.to_hash
end

def when_parser_is_done
  table_data
end
```